# RavenDB - MapReduce Complex Aggregation

Tags: .net, linq, mapreduce, ravendb, reduce

I have a document like this:

```
 order : 1
     event : { timestamp: 1/1/2012, employeeName: "mick" },
     event : { timestamp: 1/1/2012, employeeName: "mick" },
     event : { timestamp: 1/2/2012, employeeName: "rick" },
     event : { timestamp: 1/3/2012, employeeName: "mick" }

  order : 2
     event : { timestamp: 1/2/2012, employeeName: "mick" },
     event : { timestamp: 1/2/2012, employeeName: "rick" }
```

I want to run a map-reduce query to return a list of results grouped by date with a count of employee events per order.

In this case Mick had 2 events on the 1/1 on a single order. All the other days had a single event by employee on each order on the 2 and 3 of november. So i need a MAP function with results that would look like:

```
{ orderId: 1, date: 1/1/2012, employee: "mick", orderEventsCount: 2 },
{ orderId: 1, date: 1/2/2012, employee: "rick", orderEventsCount: 1 },
{ orderId: 2, date: 1/2/2012, employee: "mick", orderEventsCount: 1 },
{ orderId: 2, date: 1/2/2012, employee: "rick", orderEventsCount: 1 },
{ orderId: 1, date: 1/3/2012, employee: "mick", orderEventsCount: 1 }
```

Then i need a REDUCE function that will take these results and group by Date only and return a count per day of employees with multiple events on a single order:

```
{ date: 1/1/2012, multipleEventsPerOrdercount: 1 },
{ date: 1/2/2012, multipleEventsPerOrdercount: 0 },
{ date: 1/3/2012, multipleEventsPerOrdercount: 0 }
```

Since Mick was the only employee to have multiple events on a single date on a single order the result returned only a count of one employee with multiple events on an order on a date.

What would be the best way to write this map-reduce Raven query using LINQ in .NET?

Thanks

Comment: Are those two separate order documents? Or one document with two orders in it?  Also, dates will never make their way into the document the way you showed.  Are you using a DateTime property in your class?  Please show your client-side code, or indicate if you are making direct http calls.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. These are two separate order documents. The dates are stored in the RavenDB JSON document as timestamp fields e.g. "2012-11-08T02:32:13.5549981" and deserialized to a Date field in the Entity classes objects. I don't think the client-side code is relevant here, this is purely a backend computational problem. I Just need a pure map-reduce solution using RavenDB Indexes using LINQ in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your classes look like this:

```
public class Order
{
  public string Id  { get; set; }
  public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
  public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

Then the index you are asking for would look like this:

```
public class Orders_EventCountsByDate : 
    AbstractIndexCreationTask<Order, Orders_EventCountsByDate.Result>
{
  public class Result
  {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Count { get; set; }
  }

  public Orders_EventCountsByDate()
  {
    Map = orders => from order in orders
                    from evt in order.Events
                    let subtotal = order.Events.Count(x => x.EmployeeName == evt.EmployeeName && x.Timestamp == evt.Timestamp)
                    select new
                    {
                      evt.Timestamp.Date,
                      Count = subtotal > 1 ? (1.0 / subtotal) : 0
                    };

    Reduce = results => from result in results
                        group result by result.Date
                        into g
                        select new
                        {
                          Date = g.Key,
                          Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                        };
  }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
var counts = session.Query<Orders_EventCountsByDate.Result,
                           Orders_EventCountsByDate>();
```

The trick here is that you are making a determination in the Map about how much you want each event to contribute to the count.  If there is only one event, you contribute zero.  When there are multiple events, each event contributes a fraction of the total.  These fractions are later summed up in the reduce, returning you to near whole numbers.  The double floating point math should get you back to whole numbers, but you still may want to round to the nearest whole integer in your client side code just to be safe.

This also assumes that all events are in the same timezone and you don't care about daylight savings changes, or the times are in UTC.  If neither, then you should use DateTimeOffset and you have more to consider when deciding what each employee's concept of a Day is.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your question and realized you were not looking for a simple count by date, but one that only counts employees with more than one order on the same date.  I will have an updated answer shortly.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to fit your question.  As you can see, there is some math involved, which is why probably why the answer was elusive.